How to recreate the "view" features of common voice v11 in HuggingFace?
The Common Voice v11 on HuggingFace has some amazing View features! They include a dropdown button to select the language, and columns with the dataset features, such as client_id, audio,  sentence, etc.
I am building an audio dataset for 7 languages. I have split the audio into multiple parts giving me two sets of files: 1.mp3, 2.mp3, etc. And the corresponding transcription: 1.txt, 2.txt, etc.
These files are distributed into three folders: train, test, and validate for each language.
I am able to upload the data to HuggingFace, but how do I format the View option, such that:

I can select the language from a dropdown list
Then select the type of data: train, test, validate
View three columns: client_id, audio,  sentence

Thank you!

It took me a while to find a solution. But here is what worked for me to recreate the view features of Mozilla's Common Voice on HuggingFace:
Ensure that you use the push_to_hub method with the subset and split parameters.
Here's a pseudo code outline:

Set up your environment:

Install the required libraries.
Authenticate with Hugging Face using your token.



# Install necessary libraries
pip install datasets huggingface_hub pandas

# Import required modules
import os
from datasets import Dataset, Audio
from huggingface_hub import HfApi, HfFolder

# Authenticate with Hugging Face
hf_token = 'your_hf_token'
HfFolder.save_token(hf_token)


Create a repository if it doesn't exist:

Use the HfApi to check and create the repository.



# Initialize API
api = HfApi()
repo_id = 'your_repo_id'

# Function to create repo if not exists
def create_repo_if_not_exists(repo_id, hf_token):
    try:
        api.create_repo(repo_id=repo_id, token=hf_token, repo_type='dataset')
    except Exception as e:
        if "409 Client Error: Conflict" in str(e):
            pass  # Repo already exists
        else:
            raise e


Load and process your data splits:

Iterate through your data directory to load audio and text files.
Create a Dataset object for each split.



# Function to load and process each split
def load_split(data_dir, split, language):
    data = []
    folder_path = os.path.join(data_dir, language, split)
    if os.path.exists(folder_path):
        for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
            if file_name.endswith(".mp3"):
                audio_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
                text_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name.replace(".mp3", ".txt"))
                if os.path.exists(text_path):
                    with open(text_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        sentence = f.read().strip()
                    data.append({"client_id": int(file_name.replace(".mp3", "")), "audio": audio_path, "sentence": sentence})
    if data:
        dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data))
        return dataset
    return None


Push the datasets to Hugging Face Hub:

Iterate through languages and splits.
Push datasets using the push_to_hub method with appropriate parameters.



data_dir = 'path_to_your_data_directory'
languages = ["en", "pt", "de"]
splits = ["train", "test", "val"]

for language in languages:
    for split in splits:
        dataset = load_split(data_dir, split, language)
        if dataset:
            dataset = dataset.cast_column("audio", Audio())
            create_repo_if_not_exists(repo_id, hf_token)
            dataset.push_to_hub(repo_id, subset=language, split=split)

This approach ensures that the Viewer pane on Hugging Face will display both subset and split dropdowns correctly, provided you have more than one subset.
